# property value not getting passed to other method

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

In my header file I declared a new property like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *porperty;
```

In my implementation file I give the property a value:

```
-method1{
 self.property = someString;
 NSLog(@"property = %@", self.property);
}
```

The log shows up in the debugger as the same value of someString.  Okay great, but when i try to use this property in the next method of the same implemtation file it loses its value.

```
-method2{
 NSLog(@"property = %@", self.property);
}
```

Now the debugger says (null).

Simple question. i know but this usually works for me.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because someString has been released on next cycle.
Replace weak by strong, this will retain your string.

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *porperty;